# Over 100 pins ic packages in Eagle

Tags: pcb, schematics, eaglecad, orcad

I want to use Eagle or Kicad to design a board using Maxim chips MAXQ1103 and MAX32550

http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAXQ1103.pdf

and

http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX32550.pdf

MAXQ1103 is 144 pins TQFP package (see page 1 of the above datasheet)

while

MAX32550 is 121 CSBGA package   (see page 2 of the above datasheet)

The question is i am not able to find these parts in the Eagle's library (my google search didn't help me much). Where can i find these parts or do i have to create myself? If so, is it really worth the effort (how hard is it for Eagle beginner)?

The reference schematics of both these chips are done in Cadence ORCAD, which is very expensive to purchase.

Thanks